# GAE: Request needs more than 30s

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, timeout

How can I disable the Google App Engine request timeout for a specific cron/request.

I'm creating some routines that need more than 30s of processing, and the GAE alwayes terminate my routine.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is [Task Queues](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) which have 10 min time limit.

The other is [Backends](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html), which have no time limits.

Comment: I'm doing through backend cron, but I'm getting timeout with 30s

Comment: Are you doing any URLFetch? It has 5s timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at task queues. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used the backend to run tasks required more CPU times and it works well.
Although it is based on python, I believe the concept should be the same.

A. Use cron to execute tasks
For example:

> ```
> cron:
> - description: Start Backend to parse the log
>   url: /_ah/start/ParseLog/
>   schedule: every day 00:00
> ```

B. The tasks executed by cron are running in front end, so it still has time limit. Thus, I forward the task to backend (named "worker") to avoid time restriction.

> ```
> class ParseLogStarter(webapp.RequestHandler):
>     # run on frontend
>     def get(self):
>         self.post()
>
>     def post(self):
>         date = self.request.get("date")
>         # do nothing but forwarding to backend "worker"
>         taskqueue.add(url="/_ah/ParseLog/", params={"date":date}, target='worker')
> ```

C. On the backend, receive the forwarded tasks and working on the routines job.

> ```
> class ParseLogWorker(webapp.RequestHandler):
>     # run on backends
>     def get(self):
>         self.post()
>
>     def post(self):
>         # do your routines job here
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree, you can use task queues, these have a timeout of 10 minutes, i just have used task queues in a recent project and i have done a little code to re-enqueue the same task with convenient params if a need more than 10 minutos, so i'm avoiding use backends that are more expensive.